# Custom folds for cross-validation in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to use GridSearchCV (with n_jobs > 1) for a particular classifier, but I have information about the folds for 10-fold cross-validation from another source. Is there some way to input data already divided into folds instead of using the folds created by GridSearchCV.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a custom CV iterator, for instance by taking inspiration on  [LeaveOneGroupOut](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#leave-one-group-out) or [LeaveOneGroupOut](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#leave-one-group-out) to implement the structure you are interested in.

Alternatively you can prepare your own precomputed folds encoded as an array of integers (representing sample indices between `0` and `n_samples - 1`) and then pass that CV iterator as the `cv` argument of the `cross_val_score` and `GridSearchCV` utilities:

```py
>>> X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10)
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
>>> cv_splits = [
...     (np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6])),
...     (np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), np.array([5, 6, 7])),
...     (np.array([5, 6, 8, 9]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])),
... ]
>>> cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(), X, y, cv=cv_splits)
array([1.        , 0.33333333, 0.75      ])
```

Comment: Looks like `LeaveOneLabelOut` has been replaced with [`LeaveOneGroupOut`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer with your fix and more details.